# Issue while Comparing Strings

Tags: java, string, compare

I have a problem with the following:

I have a sequence that comes with the value:

"ORA-00904: TESTE: identificador inválido"

I need to replace this test field to empty ( '') in my query .

But if my query contains other field with the name for example TESTETE and I replace for '', it staies wrong, replacing TESTE for `and TESTETE for`TE

I want to replace the TESTE for `` and the TESTETE let how it is.

---

my example query is :

SELECT TESTE, TESTETE, fld1 FROM TBL

---

My logic is as follows:

```
String oracleMsg = "ORA-00904: TESTE: identificador inválido";
String query = "SELECT TESTE, TESTETE, OUTRO FROM TBL";
String comp = "TESTE";

if (oracleMsg.contains(comp)){
    query = query.replace(comp, "''");
}
System.out.println(query);
```

Result:  SELECT '', ''TE, OUTRO FROM TBL
Expected Result? SELECT '', TESTETE, OUTRO FROM TBL

Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: you can expand your comp var to "TESTE," and replace it with '', but this will rise an issue when the field you replace is the last one (the missing ',' at the end of the field list)

Comment: I Can`t do it friend. Because "TESTE" comes dynamically in my system. What i posted here was just an examplo. 

Other sugestions ???

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions and surround your pattern with word-boundary anchors.

```
 query = query.replaceAll("\\b"+comp+"\\b", "''");
```

In case you want to replace only one instance of the pattern, use `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: Hello Joni, your way is good. I Could fix my problem with you solution. Thank you!